# why is surveyyr coming up as integer (empty)?

Tags: r, subset

Why does `integer(empty)` come up in the global environment when I do this:

`year 1 = which(SurveyYr == "2009_2010")`?

Comment: Is `SurveyYr` a variable inside a data frame that has another name?

Comment: year 1 is not a legal object name, try year_1 or enclose it in backticks.

Comment: yes it is, does that just mean that I did SurveyYr = NHANES$SurveyYr?